# How does $\bigl( \sqrt{n^2+n} + n \bigr)\cdot \frac{1}{n}$ lead to $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} + 1$

Tags: calculus, limits

We want to find the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n^2+n}-n$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n^2+n}-n  = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\bigl(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n\bigr) \bigl(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n\bigr)}{\bigl(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n\bigr)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2+n-n^2}{\bigl(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n\bigr)} \\
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n \cdot \frac{1}{n}}{\bigl( \sqrt{n^2+n} + n \bigr) \frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} + 1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

What I don't understand is the last part. How does $\bigl( \sqrt{n^2+n} + n \bigr) \frac{1}{n}$ lead to $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} + 1$ ?

Wouldn't that just be $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}{n } + \frac{n}{n} = \frac{n \bigl(\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}}{n} +1\big)}{n} + 1 = \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1} + 1}{n} + 1?$

Clarification would be appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't change your question in a way that makes existing answers invalid, unless there is good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that:
$$\sqrt{n^2+n}+n = \sqrt{n^2 \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)} + n = n \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} +n = n \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} +1 \right)$$

Now, the extra factor $\frac{1}{n}$ multiplied by the $n$ that appears outside of everything above is just $1$ so you get what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

$$\bigl( \sqrt{n^2+n} + n \bigr) \frac{1}{n}=\frac{ \sqrt{n^2+n} + n}{n}=\frac{ \sqrt{n^2+n}}{n}+1=\sqrt{\frac{n^2+n }{n^2}}+1=\sqrt{1+\frac{1 }{n}}+1$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}{n} +1$ in the second step?

Comment: No, because $A\cdot\frac{1}{B}=\frac{A}{B}$, where $A=\bigl( \sqrt{n^2+n} + n \bigr)$ and $B=n$

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$

$\frac{n \cdot \frac{1}{n}}{\bigl( \sqrt{n^2+n} + n \bigr) \frac{1}{n}} = \frac{n \cdot \cancel{\frac{1}{n}}}{\bigl( \sqrt{n^2+n} + n \bigr) \cancel{\frac{1}{n}}} =\frac{n}{n(\sqrt{\frac{n^2 + n}{n^2}}+1)}=\frac{\cancel n}{\cancel n(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} + 1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} + 1}$

Let's see your work:

> Wouldn't that just be $[\bigl( \sqrt{n^2+n} + n \bigr) \frac{1}{n}]=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}\color{red}{\cancel{+n}}}{n } + \frac{n}{n} = \frac{n \bigl(\frac{\sqrt{n^2+\cancel{\color{red}1}}^{\color{green}n}}{n}\color{red}{\cancel{ + 1}}\big)}{n} + 1 = \frac{\sqrt{n^2+\color{red}{\cancel 1}^{\color{green}n}}\color{red}{\cancel{ + 1}}}{n} + 1$?

There's the problems: 1) you left an $n$ in, and 2) you then reduced it too soon

The next step would have been:$ \frac{\sqrt{n^2+\color{red}{\cancel 1}^{\color{green}n}}\color{red}{\cancel{ + 1}}}{n} + 1=\sqrt{\frac {n^2 +n}{n^2}}+1=\sqrt{n+\frac 1n}+1$